# implement view and view controller using segment control in view controller

Tags: objective-c

Is there any solution to implement a `View` and a `ViewController` using `segment control` in `ViewController`?

I tried creating a `ChildViewController` and adding it. When I want to see the other `View` I am trying to remove the `View` using `removeFromsuperview` and removing the `ChildViewController` but its not working.

```
- (IBAction)segmentcontrol:(id)sender {
    notificationsViewController *notification=[[notificationsViewController alloc]init];


    if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {

        if(self.view==nil)
        {
            self.attendeesTableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 416);
            [self.view addSubview:self.attendeesTableView];
        }
        else
        {
            [notification willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
            [notification.view removeFromSuperview];
            [notification removeFromParentViewController];
            self.attendeesTableView.hidden=NO;
        }
    }

    else if(self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)

    {

        self.attendeesTableView.hidden = YES;
        notification.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 416);
        [self addChildViewController:notification];
        [self.view addSubview:notification.view];
        [notification didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your screen what you expecting so its easy to jump into your issue.

Comment: hello @CodeChanger whenever I am trying to switch from index 1 to index 0 the childviewcontroller is not getting removed instead it is staying on the top of attendeestableview .So if I am trying to switch it again it is again creating another childviewcontroller on the top of created childviewcontroller....